# G. 723.1 How to use codecs

Tags: g729

`your text`[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eNms.png)
`your text`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxrAV.png)
`your text`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTYpD.png)
`your text`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y68Cj.png)

```
`According to the coding and decoding case, it is currently unknown What is a TIN file and what is the correct format for an operation? Thank you very much for your answer. Thank you very much
I tried to follow his case and then compare, and both the comparison and operation results were correct, but I am not sure about this What does a TIN file represent, and then Is TCO file a source file?`
```

Comment: G.723.1Audio Codec

Comment: Hi, I don't want to sound harsh, but did you ACTUALLY take a look at the question you asked? The formatting (or rather the hard-to-parse mess) alone gives the impression you do not care at all about the question, and if YOU do not care about it, why should anyone else care or even try to answer it?